# Getting child elements of dynamic generated content with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="item-content" style="display: block;">
<div class="item-menu">
<div id="ajax-content-1" style="display: block; opacity: 0;">
<div class="content chapters current-tab">
<div class="right">
<div id="chapters-container-8" style="">
<div id="chapters-container-7" style="display: none">
<div id="chapters-container-6" style="display: none">
<div id="chapters-container-5" style="display: none">
<div id="chapters-container-4" style="display: none">
<div id="chapters-container-3" style="display: none">
<div id="chapters-container-25" style="display: none">
<div id="chapters-container-1" style="display: none">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is an ajax content , and I have several on the page. So what I want to do is display the 1st chapter-container visible on the page
if i do this:

```
var first_div = $('div[id^=chapters-container-]:first');
first_div.show();
```

it doesn't work because it shows all the visible chapter-containers divs on the page, I want it to show only the one for that ajax-content I have loaded. I tried doing something like:

```
var first_div = $('#ajax-content-' + id).closest('div[id^=chapters-container-]:first');
first_div.show();
```

and

```
var first_div = $('#ajax-content-' + id).children('div[id^=chapters-container-]:first');
first_div.show();
```

and it doesnt't work. btw i know the var id, so it is no error there. It simply doesn't make a good selection of what I want.

Comment: Please format the code in your question.

Comment: You're not showing any of your closing tags. Using `:first`, `closest()`, and `children()` will all be affected by DOM structure. Make sure you're showing your exact code including closing tags, or we can only guess at solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a jQuery element which is not in the DOM, append the content from the AJAX request there and perform selecting on that element then. Let me show you how:

```
$.ajax({

// some ajax options etc.

success: function( data ) {
    var container = $('<div>').apppend(data),
    firstChapter = container.find('div[id^=chapters-container-]:first');
}

});
```

This way you are operating on elements outside the DOM (which is faster BTW) and you can later append them wherever you want.

And by the way you could give the chapter containers a class for easier and faster selecting.